# get query string url in sharepoint report

Tags: reporting-services, parameter

how can I get query string in a report url and use it in my report?

I try these ways and no one works right!

Method (1)

```
http://<your server>/ReportServer?/<folder>/<reportname>&STUDENT_ID=5
```

Method (2)

```
http://<server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<path>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render&UserID='fred'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the query string parameters like given below

//myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008

and if your're working in SharePoint integrated Report server it should be referenced through /_vti_bin path like below

//myspsite/subsite/_vti_bin/reportserver?http://myspsite/subsite/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2.rdl&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008

Please refer this article for more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the single quotation **`'`** from the `parameter value` to be like the following :

```
http://<server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?
%2f<path>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render&UserID=fred
```

**Note :**

- Make sure that the parameter name in report URL is the same name of the parameter that defined in the report.
- To get the correct report URL , navigate to `http://<server>/ReportServer/` then open your report .
- To add the parameter correctly at the end of your report URL add **&** followed by `parameter name`(UserID) as defined in report followed by `your value` (fred) without single quotation **`'`**

**Example :**

By applying the above-mentioned notes , If you have a report called `Qassas` that have a defined parameter called `UserID` that placed inside a Folder called `Qassas Folder` and you need to filter `UserID` with the value `fred` so the Report Url Should be

```
 http://<server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?
 %2fQassas+Folder%2fQassas&rs:Command=Render&UserID=fred
```

For **integrated Mode** try to add **`rp:`**  before the parameter name , so your Url should like

```
http://portal/sites/BICenter/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?
rv:RelativeReportUrl=/sites/BICenter/ReportLibrary/NewReport.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rp:UserID=fred
```

Comment: as you said i create this url, but does not  work.
http://portal/sites/BICenter/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/sites/BICenter/ReportLibrary/NewReport.rdl&rs:Command=Render&UserID=fred

Comment: Based on your question its native mode , based on the comment its integrated mode , so check my updated answer for integrated mode :) , and please don't hesitate to tell me if you still face issue or need more clarification

Answer (score 0):

I find out correct addressing

```
http://{site address}/_vti_bin/reportserver?{report address}&reportparamater=1
```

this addressing works for me like:

```
http://portal/_vti_bin/reportserver?http://BICenter/ReportLibrary/NewReport.rdl&Id=355
```